# representing time interval in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know that there is a data type called `NSTimeInterval`, but this is in seconds. I want to have an object representation that would be able to represent a time range, say Thursday 21 June 8:00 - Thursday 21 June 9:00. Later on I want to compare the current date/time and check whether it fits within this range. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using two NSDate objects to store the start and end dates. You can easily determine if a date is between them using the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method:

```
- (BOOL)dateInInterval:(NSDate *)testDate {
    // date1 is the instance variable containing the starting date
    // date2 is the instance variable containing the ending date
    return ([testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date1] > 0 &&
            [testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] < 0);
}
```

You just need to make a class which holds two NSDate objects, making sure the first is before the second, and including this method.

FYI, NSTimeInterval is not a class, its a typedef of double.

**Edit**

Since you want use these as keys for a dictionary, you could use something similar to this to store and search your data:

```
@protocol IntervalDictionaryKey <NSObject>
// The class you use as keys for your dictionary must implement this method to determine if a object is in the interval
- (BOOL)intervalContains:(id)object;
@end
@interface IntervalDictionary : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *keys, *values;
}
- (void)addInterval:(id<IntervalDictionaryKey>)interval withObject:(id)object;
- (void)setObject:(id)object forIntervalOf:(id)intervalObject;
- (id)objectForIntervalOf:(id)object;
@end


@implementation IntervalDictionary
- (id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        keys = [NSMutableArray new];
        values = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [keys release];
    [values release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)addInterval:(id<IntervalDictionaryKey>)interval withObject:(id)object {
    [keys addObject:interval];
    [values addObject:object];
}
- (void)setObject:(id)object forIntervalOf:(id)intervalObject {
    id<IntervalDictionaryKey> key;
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for(key in keys) {
        if([key intervalContains:intervalObject]) {
            [values replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:object];
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
- (id)objectForIntervalOf:(id)object {
    id<IntervalDictionaryKey> key;
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for(key in keys) {
        if([key intervalContains:object]) {
            return [values objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
@end
```

Usage:

Example interval class:

```
@interface DateInterval : NSObject <IntervalDictionaryKey> {
    NSDate *date1, *date2;
}
- (BOOL)intervalContains:(NSDate *)date; // this is the same as the dateInInterval method above
@end
@implementation DateInterval
// initializer which sets date1 and date2
- (BOOL)intervalContains:(NSDate *)date {
    return ([date timeIntervalSinceDate:date1] > 0 &&
            [date timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] < 0);
}
@end
```

Example usage code:

```
//intervalX is a DateInterval object, created elsewhere
//objectX is any object, created elsewhere
//objectInX is a NSDate which is part of intervalX, created elsewhere
IntervalDictionary *dict = [IntervalDictionary new];
[dict addInterval:interval0 withObject:object0];
[dict addInterval:interval1 withObject:object1];
[dict objectForIntervalOf:objectIn0]; // returns object0
[dict objectForIntervalOf:objectIn1]; // returns object1
[dict setObject:object2 forIntervalOf:objectIn1]; // changes the object for interval1 to object2
[dict objectForIntervalOf:objectIn1]; // now returns object2
```

Comment: would it change your answer if the date is always the same date?

Comment: Then you could just store the offset from the reference date, but it won't make much difference in use.

Comment: The problem is that the starting date and the ending date is changing

Comment: Then you need to provide properties so you can change it, or just create a new object.

Comment: the time interval would actually be a key to a dictionary, the issue now is that what should this time interval be... a string? or what is the most appropriate...

Comment: maybe I should create a class called timeinterval it self that has a beginning time and ending time and this will be the key to my dictionary?

Comment: NSDictionary only allows strings as keys, and it only allows you to get objects by exactly matching the key, so it would be easier to create something similar to a dictionary yourself than to try to do this using NSDictionary. But yes, I would suggest you create a time interval class. I will add an example to my answer of how you could implement an "interval dictionary".

Comment: `NSDictionary` allows a lot more than just strings as keys, you can use any object that adheres to the `NSCopying` protocol. If you wish to use KVC, however, the keys should be instances of `NSString` (or subclasses).

Comment: What if I just represent the intervals as NSString and then parse that to a NSDate format to check if the current time is within an interval? Wouldn't that be much more simpler than having to create your own string?

Comment: Then there is no point in using a dictionary. You have to go through all of the keys manually and see which one it is. If you are going to do it more than once, it is easier to create a class to do it for you.

Comment: There is actually a point. Once I know that the current time is within the time interval (which is a key in the dictionary), then I can use the object stored in the dictionary associated with that key..

Comment: Would it make sense to set the "interval" object as a key, but when you want to retrieve the value from this custom dictionary I give it a time stamp (7:00 pm) instead of an "interval" object

Comment: The code I posted would take some object and pass it to a method of each key (interval). What you pass would depend on the implementation of the key, so if the interval's `intervalContains:` method expected a timestamp, that's what you would pass.

Comment: and that means I'd have to change the implementation of - (id)objectForIntervalOf:(id)object right? as object here is a timestamp

Comment: what I want to do is basically to have - (void)setObject:(id)object forIntervalOf:(id)intervalObject where intervalObject here is a interval object and  (id)objectForIntervalOf:(id)object right where object here is a time stamp.. what do I need to modify in order to have that?

Comment: `objectForIntervalOf:` doesn't care what it gets, just the keys. You would need to change your interval objects to accept the timestamp in their `intervalContains:` method. The way I posted it, you use `addInterval:withObject:` to add an interval with a specific object, and `setObject:forIntervalOf:` to change the object, but that takes just one object which is in the interval. You could change it, or add a new method, which takes the interval object instead. I'll add an example usage.

Comment: yea..mind showing me the changes in the code above on how to do this?

Comment: if I want to create a class called interval it needs to implement the method - (BOOL)intervalContains:(id)object ?

Comment: Yes. `intervalContains:` would be like `dateInInterval:`. It tells the dictionary whether or not the object is in the interval, so the dictionary doesn't have to know what the intervals are.

Comment: So actually I can do [dict objectForIntervalOf:[NSDate date]]; with the code above? I am assuming not right? That's actually what I want..

Comment: Yes, that would set the object for the interval containing the current date.

Comment: sorry I changed my question above

Comment: objectInX will always be a [NSDate date] in my case, so I am guess that changes the implementation of my intervalContains to - (BOOL)intervalContains:(NSDate *)timestamp and remove the date

Comment: That would be right if you change `intervalContains:` to be exactly like `dateInInterval:`. I set it up to use strings, but you can just change the argument type to NSDate and use that instead of creating one from the string. It would give you the object for the first interval matching the current date.

Comment: might not be a relevant question to the original topic, but what if I want to save this IntervalDictionary, so that when I quit the app I can directly access all the data in it? How do I save and open it each time I update something to it in the iphone?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use NSCoding and NSArchiver. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i. You would need to implement NSCoding on the dictionary as well as the interval objects.

Comment: Two things to fix: NSObject does not support coding, so remove the call to `[super encodeWithCoder:]` in the Interval class, and you need to use `mutableCopy` when decoding the arrays in the dictionary class or you will get un-mutable arrays, with no compiler warning or error.

Comment: why am I also getting warnings on if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) on NSObjects? should I remove this as well?

Comment: Yes, you should. I missed that because you only did it in the dictionary and not the interval.

Comment: why does this tutorial http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding has that super initWithCoder then? it uses a NSObject as well

Comment: Either it will cause a crash or they used a category to add a default implementation to initWithCoder. You should simply use init.

Comment: Instead of `[super initWithCoder:]`, just use `[super init]`.

Comment: inside your setObject forIntervalOf... what if initially there is no key? You are iterating through a set of keys (for(key in keys)), initially it is empty

Comment: I am kind of confused what's the objectX purpose here

Comment: objectX represents the values associated with the intervals. You are right, I did not handle the situation where there is no matching interval. You could either have a default object, which would require adding a property, or you could just return nil.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can be used to store components of time intervals as well as date components. You can add such an object to an NSDate using NSCalendar's [`dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a).

Answer (score 0):

From iOS10+ you have **NSDateInterval** (See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateinterval?language=objc).
Is the best data structure to represent a time interval.